# Access Form Controls Flicker on control being setFocus from Class

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have been working on getting the flickering on a Access Form to stop.
The same problem appears in Access 2013 and 2016.

I have 24 toggle buttons on a form. Due to certain limitations of OptionGroup control, I have built all the functionality I need into a group of Toggle Buttons instead. This is attached to the buttons through a class for each set of buttons.

Everything is working correctly but when the user presses left, right, up or down arrows the controls flicker.

The Code:

```
Private Sub tglS_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    If Shift = 1 Then Exit Sub
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 39, 40
            KeyCode = 0
            tglSI.SetFocus
            tglSI.Value = True
            tglSI_AfterUpdate
        Case 37, 38
            KeyCode = 0
            tglNA.SetFocus
            tglNA.Value = True
            tglNA_AfterUpdate
    End Select
End Sub
```

I have stepped through the code and found it is whenever a control is `SetFocus`.

All controls flicker both bound and unbound controls. The toggle buttons are on a tab page and flickers the controls off the tab as well.

I have tried placing `Application.Echo` statements on each side of the `SetFocus` statement but no change.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell if you did this so just to be sure, did you set a value to echo?

```
Application.Echo False
Select Case KeyCode
    Case 39, 40
        KeyCode = 0
        tglSI.SetFocus
        tglSI.Value = True
        tglSI_AfterUpdate
    Case 37, 38
        KeyCode = 0
        tglNA.SetFocus
        tglNA.Value = True
        tglNA_AfterUpdate
End Select
Application.Echo True
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have tried with no change in result.

Answer (score 0):

your code refers to a function tglSI_AfterUpdate and tglNA_AfterUpdate - do those functions or subroutines change the echo of the form? I have had bad luck with the echo actually causing the flicker, along with conditional formatting that may alter the visibility of controls during events too.  Do the toggle buttons have images on them or text?

Comment: It flickers on the set focus even if the only thing it does is ‘Application.Echo False: tglSI.Value = True: Application.Echo True’ the after update pushes a value to a remote server. But that code gets called through updating the toggle. And doesn’t flicker then. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Also only text no pictures anywhere on form